# Xcode keeps asking if I want to open a playground

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

If I want to open a playground downloaded from the internet, I get asked if I want to open that playground. I say yes, but it keeps asking each time I get back to it.

The problem occurs with [this NSHipster playground](http://nshipster.com/xcplayground/).

No other steps required.

Xcode version is 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Any way to fix this?

To clarify: I have "Anywhere" checked in my security settings.

I also tried doing a `chown` and `chmod`, but doesn't help.

Comment: Can you add the steps required to recreate this problem? Which version of Xcode?

Comment: Such kind of problems often go away when clearing cache and derived data.

Comment: Adding the playgrounds to the workspace don't have anything to do with it. I downloaded [this](http://nshipster.com/xcplayground/) playground and tried opening that one multiple times and the error remains.

Comment: @ThomasKilian tried deleting derived data, doesn't work.

Comment: It might also be a preferences problem. Maybe a `defaults delete com.apple.Xcode` might help?

Comment: @ThomasKilian `defaults` can't find the `com.apple.Xcode` domain. I also tried `chown -R username:staff` and even `chmod -R 777`, but doesn't work as well...

Comment: You should do as @DanielStorm suggests and provide the steps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ThomasKilian No steps required as it seems (edited to improve this). It works with the playground currently up on `NSHipster`'s homepage, as linked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to your security settings:

[image]

Check if you have anywhere checked.

Comment: I have anywhere checked, still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with xcode 6.3.2. I got the issue when I downloaded it via ibook link. Once I downloaded it via we, it worked. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1

My previous version was playground version='1.0' and the new one also same. But it includes lots of new libraries.